# How to divide the webview content in multiple pages

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, canvas

I have to create PDF from my webView using PdfDocument on Android.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html
The pdf is created well but it is only one page document.

```
// create a new document
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

// create a page description
PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(width,         
height, 1).create();

// start 1st page
Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
// draw something on the page
View content = myWebview;
content.draw(page.getCanvas());
// finish 1st page
document.finishPage(page);

// start 2nd page
Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
// draw something on the page
View content = someOtherWebview;
content.draw(page.getCanvas());
// finish 2nd page
document.finishPage(page);

// and so on...

FileOutputStream out;
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(fileNameWithPath, false);
    // write the document content
     document.writeTo(out);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

// close the document
document.close();
```

How can I divide webview content in pages?

Answer (score 1):

I am creating an android app that reads a file like a book, but instead of chopping it up and displaying one page at a time, I hide all but one of the sections and then just display the entire file.

So perhaps you could use a similar technique something like:

**1.** You can hide all of the webview with css 
**2.** reveal one section 
**3.** write to the PDF 
**4.** hide the previous section 
**5.** reveal the next etc.

In your text.html source file read by your webview, wrap each page in div tags like this:

```
<div id="page1" style="display:hidden;">
    Page 1 text
</div>
<div id="page2" style="display:hidden;">
    Page 2 text
</div>
<div id="page3" style="display:hidden;">
    Page 3 text
</div>
```

In your Java:

```
//First you have to enable Javascript
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//Then run this javascript which will find the first page and reveal it
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('page"+ 1 +"').style.display ='block';");
//reload Webview
webView.loadUrl("C:\Desktop\text.html");
//write to PDF
//repeat for page 2
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Was this helpful? Not? Have questions? Let me know.